# How to get json response image path in ajax while post formdata?

Tags: ajax, json, file-upload, form-data

**Currently i am using ajax formdata for sending file in ajax . But json     give     me output just file name not full path of image .let me know how can get   image full path and image upload in folder .

//code here**

```
<?php      
if(isset($_POST)){   
$data = $_FILES['file-0']['name'];    
$file = 'upload/'. $_FILES['file-0']['name'];     
$success = file_put_contents($file, $data);     
json_encode($data);   
}
?>   
<Script>    
$(".btnSubmit").click(function(){   
var data = new FormData();  
jQuery.each(jQuery('.inputFile')[0].files, function(i, file) {  
    data.append('file-'+i, file);    
}); 

$.ajax({  
            type: 'POST',  
            url: 'check.php',    
  contentType: false,   
    processData: false,   
            data: data  

        })  
        .done(function(data){   
         $(".response").html("<img src="+data+">");     

        })    
        .fail(function() {   
                    // just in case posting your form failed
            alert( "Posting failed." );   

        });   
        // to prevent refreshing the whole page page
        return false;   

});    
</script>
```